# Como remover a opção do submenu "extrair aqui" de um sfx (exe)?

Tags: windows, submenu

Há como remover a opção "extrair aqui" de um arquivo sfx (.exe) criado com o winrar?

Obs.: A opção "extrair aqui" é apresentada no submenu, ao clicar com o botão direito sob o arquivo. Qualquer outro .exe contanto que não seja um sfx não apresenta essa opção.

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de remover essa opção.

Comment: Até onde eu sei isso é um recurso do programa, configurável durante a instalação do WinRAR. O fato de existir uma entrada no menu de contexto talvez seja característica do WinRAR para arquivos que ele conhece como sendo pacotes auto-extraíveis.

Answer (score 2):

Siga o menu nesta sequência:

- Opções > Preferências

  - Aba Integração > Shell

    - Itens do menu de contexo

Lá você define todas as opções que desejar no menu. Pode haver alguma variação na terminologia usada, dependendo da tradução da versão em questão, mas geralmente o caminho é parecido com este.

Comment: Sim, é um menu de contexto próprio dos SFXs. A sua solução resolve o problema localmente. Mas não em outras máquinas. Há alguma linha de comando dentro do sfx (.exe) que permite o chamado desse submenu.

Comment: O problema é que provavelmente o menu não está no sfx, e sim o sfx está associado com o winrar da máquina. A opção nao deveria aparecer numa máquina sem winrar (aparece ?). Pra ser sincero, aqui só uso 7zip, que extrai .rar tambem, entao nem lembro a "cara" do winrar.

Comment: O 7z também mostra a opção no contexto. Só não aparece a opção se não for um .exe auto extraível. Eu queria impedir a extração por esse método.

Comment: Não sei se daria, mas talvez compactar o exe do SFX com UPX tivessa algum efeito em desassociar do WinRAR e consequentemente não mostrar o menu. Mas só testando mesmo.

Comment: Já fiz isso também. Não funcionou. O UPX apenas comprime o código.